# Русский язык в строковых функциях PHP.

Tags: строки, php, функции

Здравствуйте.
Собственно, возникла у меня проблема при применении строковых функций(трансформаций) к строкам, содержащим русские символы и последующей записи результата в HTML-файл.
Например, делаю так:

> ```
> $str = 'строка строка страница страница';
> $str2 = strrev($str);
> $f=fopen("htmlik.html","a+");
> fputs($f,$str2);
> fclose($f);
> ```

А в файл записываются вопросики, ромбики, квадратики, вообщем все, кроме того, что должно там на самом деле быть...
Уже и в .htaccess лез и менял там установку русской кодировки по умолчанию, но ничего не помогает! Пожалуйста, помогите мне...спасибо....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

Кодировка исходного файла однобайтовая (windows-1251 например).

Кодировка htmlik.html будет тоже windows-1251

**Вариант 2:**

Кодировка исходного файла многобайтовая (utf-8 например)

В htmlik.html будет плохой текст, поскольку strrev некорректно работает с многобайтовыми символами. Как вариант использовать

```
function mb_strrev($str, $encoding='UTF-8'){
    return mb_convert_encoding( strrev( mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-16BE', $encoding) ), $encoding, 'UTF-16LE');
}
```

вместо `strrev();` и всё будет ОК.

Comment: Второй способ помог! Огромное вам спасибо!!!